# OpenCV detect grid size in Nurikabe game

Tags: python, opencv, grid, detection, lines

I am new to programming computer vision programs in Python and OpenCV. I need to detect size of grid in this puzzle. Every grid is square or rectangle, size from 5x5 to 27x36. I need to extract every square from this picture. This picture is from screenshot, mostly I will make photo from my mobile. Things I did so far:

Convert to grayscale, then Gaussian Blur to remove noise from camera photo. Then I applied Adaptive Threshold. After that I found contours and warp it to rectangle. I tried Hough lines algorithm in OpenCV but it did gave me very bad results.

What steps should I do? Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/03DbD.jpg

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gaussian,255,0,1,13,4)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

area = gray.size
for i in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(i)> area/8:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(i,True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i,0.02*peri,True)
        cv2.drawContours(img,[approx],0,(0,255,0),2,cv2.CV_AA) 
        break
```

Comment: Did you correctly got the whole square?

Comment: Yes, I had got it. Here is the picture before making warp transform -  http://i.imgur.com/nRdDn60.jpg.

Comment: then warp it into a perfect square of size 10*no.of rows x 10*no.of cols. Then each square is 10x10 which you can easily split.

Comment: i think ur square has 10x10=100 cells. So warp it into image of 200x200 or whatever you feel ok.

Comment: Yes I already have code for making it perfect square. But picture doesn't have to be 10x10 everytime, it can be 5x5, 12x7, etc. I need some technique how to count rows and cols and then apply something to split it. But I don't know, how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by check aspect ratio? If it's square 6x6 or 10x10, how can I recognize how many cells I have?

Comment: Oops.. sorry, I didn't thought about that?